# Making a new import module, I need info where to find some documentation and tutorial about Magento ImportExport module

Tags: import, importexport

I was researching about import/export in Magento and I decided to go and implement a module that will rely on Magento's native ImportExport module (`app/code/code/Mage/ImportExport`). Where can I find some fine detailed (or even not so detailed) information or documentation on this module and how it works? The more detailed - the better.

Answer (score 0):

People have done that work before. You can for example use my module [AvS_FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) or another module as a base. Please also see the [documentation about the ImportExport format](https://www.integer-net.com/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/).